# File Not Found in CF11 even though file exists

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Well, I have been experiencing same error as discussed here:

[Coldfusion 10 File Not Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470520/coldfusion-10-file-not-found-error)

I am using Coldfusion 11 , developer edition on my Laptop , Windows 8.1 Pro (OS).

People have suggested two approaches over there to overcome this problem:

1) Setting Missing Template in CFAdmin

2) Setup onMissingTemplate function in Application.cfc

I am basically not sure with any of the approaches , however, I would like to go with the first approach. Could anyone tell me how should I set up missing template in CFadmin?

Comment: Keep in mind that setting Missing Template in CF Admin in global across *all* applications on your server, while onMissingTemplate() is specific to *the one* application where it is defined in Application.cfc.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you prefer letting the server handle the missing template? Myself, I like to handle it on a per-application basis. Some applications should never have links leading to non-existing files, others may operate on that as part of its core.

Straight from [adobe's docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/onMissingTemplate), you can use (I accidentally pulled this info from cf8 docs, but the link is to current docs and the result is largely the same.

```
<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate" returnType="boolean">
    <cfargument type="string" name="targetPage" required=true/>
    ...
    <cfreturn BooleanValue />
</cffunction>
```

For a few of my projects, I've written a CMS (Content-Management-System) that stores all the content in the database in fashion.

```
CMSPages
------------
PID PTitle PFile       PContent
1   Home   /index.cfm  <b>Hey!</b> Welcome to our gollygizmo website.
```

And then I (my real code actually uses cfincludes rather than directly in the document. You can do it either way, but it was easiest for me to demonstrate with inline code).

```
<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate" returnType="boolean">
  <cfargument type="string" name="targetPage" required=true/>
  <cftry>
    <cfquery name="FindPage">
        select * from CMSPages
         where pFile = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="nvarchar" value="#Arguments.targetPage#">
    </cfquery>
    <cfif FindPage.recordcount eq 1>
       <cfoutput query="FindPage">show page stuffs</cfoutput>
       <cfreturn true>
    <cfelse>
       <!--- Page not found, log some stuff or email stuff
          include cgi data so you know where the link came from --->
       Hey, this page doesn't exist, sorry about that.
       <cfreturn true>
    </cfif>
    <cfcatch>
      <!--- Something went wrong, log/email error info and --->
      <cfreturn false>
      <!--- We return false here to pass it back to the default error handler, which can be a handler set in cfadmin. --->
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

In such a scenario, it's probably beneficial to cache queries based on query name, you can do something like

```
<cfquery name="local.FindPage#hash(arguments.targetpage)#" cachedWithin="...">
  ...
</cfquery>

<cfset request.FindPage=local["Findpage#hash(arguments.targetpage)#"]>
```

So that the queries are cached by unique names, even though it's easily accesible in your document by a common name.

However, if you still prefer server-centric missing template handling, a simple search for `cold fusion admin missing template` will bring you [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/setting-cfml-based-missing-template.html).

> 1. In the ColdFusion Administrator, click on "Settings" to view the "Server Settings" page
> 2. Specify the absolute path that ColdFusion will use to find your error handling template